# Cannot bind model to collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to use a very static starting set of data to bind to a backbone collection. In the code below, I create my model, give it an initialization function, and create a starting data set for a property called `dataArray`.

In the collection, if I understand this correctly, I assign the model to be a single new instance of the model type I just created.

When I attempt to access the model in the collection from the view (via the `render` function), however, I'm being told by Chrome's debugger that there are not models in the collection.

Trying to learn Backbone on the fly so any hints/tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Model**

```
var DataPoint = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function (x) {
        this.setDefaults();
    },

    defaults: {
        dataArray: ""
    },

    randomize: function () {
        $.each(dataArray, function (key, item) {
            this.contract = Math.random() * (140000 - 100000 + 1) + 100000;
        });
    },

    setDefaults: function() {
        dataArray = [{ "label": "0/7yrs", "contract": 108530.17, "annReturn": "1.20%" },
            { "label": "1/7yrs", "contract": 111830.17, "annReturn": "1.63%" },
            { "label": "2/7yrs", "contract": 115311.17, "annReturn": "2.07%" },
            { "label": "3/7yrs", "contract": 118984.65, "annReturn": "2.52%" },
            { "label": "4/7yrs", "contract": 122859.65, "annReturn": "2.98%" },
            { "label": "5/7yrs", "contract": 126947.77, "annReturn": "3.46%" },
            { "label": "6/7yrs", "contract": 131260.74, "annReturn": "3.94%" },
            { "label": "7/7yrs", "contract": 135810.92, "annReturn": "4.44%" }];
    }
});
```

**Collection**

```
var DataSeries = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: new DataPoint(),

    fetch: function () {
    },

    randomize: function () {
        this.each(function (m) {
            m.randomize();
        });
    }

});
```

**View**

```
var BarGraph = Backbone.View.extend({

    "el": "#graph",

    options: {barDemo: ""},

    initialize: function (options) {

        _.bindAll(this, "render", "frame");
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
        this.collection.bind("change", this.render);

        this.options.barDemo = d3.selectAll($(this.el)).append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height + 60);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function () {

        //This displays in the console as empty brackets: []
        console.log(this.collection.models);

        //This naturally throws an error saying cannot read propety of undefined
        var data = this.collection.models.attributes.dataArray;
    },

    frame: function () {
        //this.chart.append("line").attr("y1", 0).attr("y2", h - 10).style("stroke", "#000");

        //this.chart.append("line").attr("x1", 0).attr("x2", w).attr("y1", h - 10).attr("y2", h - 10).style("stroke", "#000");
    }
});
```

**Starting jQuery function**

```
$(function() {
    var dataSeries = new DataSeries();
    new BarGraph({
        collection: dataSeries
    }).render();

    setInterval(function () {
        Randomize();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused about how `Colllection`s work.  The `model` property of the collection is not meant to be a `Model` *instance* at all: it's designed to be a `Model` *class*.  So, this line:

```
model: new DataPoint(),
```

should really be:

```
model: DataPoint
```

This is likely what is causing your problem.  When you `fetch` a `Collection` Backbone uses the `model` property to instantiate each new member of the collection.  In other words, if your fetch returns:

```
[{a: 1}, {b: 2}];
```

the `Collection` will do the following (essentially; the details aren't quite the same but this is close enough for explanatory purposes):

```
this.add(new DataPoint({a: 1}))
this.add(new DataPoint({b: 2}))
```

but back when your `model` was a `DataPoint` instance, what Backbone was doing was:

```
var x = new DataPoint();
this.add(new x({a: 1}))
this.add(new x({b: 2}))
```

which wouldn't have resulted in any `Model`s being added to your `Collection`.

Also, you seem to be a little confused about the `models` property of a `Collection`.  You have this:

```
var data = this.collection.models.attributes.dataArray;
```

but the `models` property of a `Collection`'s is an array of `Model` instances, not a `Model` itself, so it has no `attributes` property.  Each individual `Model` instance in the `Collection` does have an `attributes` property though, and you can access it by using the `Collection` `invoke` method:

```
var data = this.collection.invoke('toJSON');
```

---

P.S. One last thing: your `DataSeries` `Collection` has no `url` (or `urlRoot`) property defined, which means your `fetch` won't work because Backbone has no idea where to fetch the data from.  The `url` property should be set to a `URL` which returns the JSON for 1+ models.

Answer (score 1):

you are `overriding` collections fetch with function that does nothing, the `backbone` default fetch itself calls `sync` which fetches the collection.this is not happening with the your code resulting in no models in collection

*so try this:*

```
var DataSeries = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: new DataPoint(),

        randomize: function () {
            this.each(function (m) {
                m.randomize();
            });
        }

    });
```